# Run Ant task from Ant with custom JAVA_HOME and java.home

Tags: java, ant, environment-variables, java-home

## Context

I'm upgrading the version of Java from 8 to 17 in a repository that depends on a library. I want to build the repository with Java 17, but the library with Java 8 because it cannot be built with Java 8.

## Environment

Docker container with Java 17, but also with Java 8.

## Question

The repository builds the library by running ant tasks in that library

```xml
<ant dir="${lib-build-top}" target="all"/>
<ant dir="${lib-build-top}" target="buildjars"/>
```

In the terminal the library can be built with

```
JAVA_HOME=path/to/jdk8 ant
```

So I want to be able to do something like

```xml
set JAVA_HOME and java.home from jdk17 to jdk8
<ant dir="${lib-build-top}" target="all"/>
<ant dir="${lib-build-top}" target="buildjars"/>
change JAVA_HOME and java.home back to jdk17
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to fork a new Ant process with a different JAVA_HOME environment variable.  There’s even an example of running Ant this way in [the documentation of <exec>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

```
<condition property="jdk8-home"
           value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301">
    <os family="windows"/>
</condition>
<property name="jdk8-home" location="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"/>

<property name="ant-executable" location="${ant.home}/bin/ant"/>

<exec osfamily="unix" executable="${ant-executable}">
    <arg value="-buildfile"/>
    <arg file="${ant.file}"/>
    <arg value="all"/>
    <env key="JAVA_HOME" file="${jdk8-home}"/>
</exec>
<exec osfamily="windows" executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg file="${ant-executable}.bat"/>
    <arg value="-buildfile"/>
    <arg file="${ant.file}"/>
    <arg value="all"/>
    <env key="JAVA_HOME" file="${jdk8-home}"/>
</exec>

<exec osfamily="unix" executable="${ant-executable}">
    <arg value="-buildfile"/>
    <arg file="${ant.file}"/>
    <arg value="buildjars"/>
    <env key="JAVA_HOME" file="${jdk8-home}"/>
</exec>
<exec osfamily="windows" executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg file="${ant-executable}.bat"/>
    <arg value="-buildfile"/>
    <arg file="${ant.file}"/>
    <arg value="buildjars"/>
    <env key="JAVA_HOME" file="${jdk8-home}"/>
</exec>
```